# My SQL-statement is being executed twice (I'm a beginner)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, double

I'm very new to all of this and following a very simple tutorial.
I have a database with 2 tables. Now if I want to add a value to one of them, I go to insert, right here;

[image: image of phpmyadmin]

So when I fill in 2 values, and press any of the 'go' buttons (they all seem to have the same effect so I guess it doesn't matter which one), They both get added twice (with a unique id, of course) as shown in these screenshots;

[image: Values I fill in]

After this, the SQL statement looks like this;
INSERT INTO `nationaliteit` (`id`, `nationaliteit`) VALUES (NULL, 'Belgian'), (NULL, 'Spaniard');

And I get Belgian with id 1, Spaniard id 2, Belgian id 3 and Spaniard id 4 when I take a look at all the values in my table. Why is this?

Comment: are you clicking go also on the page that appears after with the statement on it?

Comment: I think you are clicking both Go buttons, as Clint said.

Answer (score 3):

Im gonna go out on a limb here and conclude that you are entering the data twice.

When you fill out the fields and click go, it will take you to another page with something like

> Two rows have been inserted

and it will display the query it just used to insert the data.

What is not obvious to the beginner is you do not need to then also click the go box on this page. If you do you will just execute the same query again.